# Unable to install nuget package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin -Version 2.1.0

Tags: asp.net, nuget

I'm a newbie and creating an ASP.Net empty web application (C#) project. But I got this error when installing nuget package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin -Version 2.1.0.
I don't know what's seemed to be the problem bcoz I'm using the newer version VS 2012 .Net Framework 4.5 and not VS 2010.
Tried install and uninstalling nuget packages but to no avail.

```
Error result:
Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))
Uninstalling 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 2.1.0'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 2.1.0'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Failed to add reference to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core'.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin -Version 2.1.0
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

What's seemed to be the problem?

N.B: For reasons unknown, I had the same problem with installing nuget Package EntityFramework Version 6.1.1 but managed to resolve it by adding package.config file to the project. 
Many thanks indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd the same problem as did you,I don't know what was wrong.I created a couple of projects to check it and nothing worked, I thought the issue was with my frame work as It targets only above 4.0 and VS 12 and above. But that wasn't the problem.
After some time I tried to install them again and out of the blue I don't know How they just got installed. I will suggest to restart the VS or system that might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Starting Visual Studio as Administrator in combination with using the Package Manager Console seems to help.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you have to change the package source in the Package Manager Console, then you can type your command. I faced the same problem, and I wondered why I can't install the package by typing the command.

[image]